# Help deleting rows mysql

Tags: mysql

I would really apreciate some help to delete the rows returned by this query:

```
select count(av.sesskey) as total from also_viewed av where av.sesskey not in(select op.sesskey from orders_products op) group by av.sesskey having total = 1
```

Thank you very much to all

Comment: Are you trying to delete all the av.sesskey rows?

Comment: no, only the ones returned by the select above

Comment: That query doesn't return any actual rows - it returns a count...

Comment: the problem with teh query before is that it will delete also the repeated rows that I want to keep undeleted

Comment: Yes I know i have re-edited it, thx!

Comment: The query above return 70,532 rows I want to delete, the count (as total) indicate that are unique rows. Because its are grouped by  av.sesskey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE 
av1
FROM also_viewed av1,
     (SELECT count(av.sesskey) as total, av.sesskey as key 
      FROM also_viewed av 
      WHERE av.sesskey NOT IN (SELECT op.sesskey FROM orders_products op) GROUP BY av.sesskey HAVING total = 1) AS innerQuery
WHERE av1.sesskey = innerQuery.key
```

After the DELETE keyword and the FROM keyword you can specify the tables on wich you want to eliminate the matches rows.

Comment: DELETE 
av1
FROM also_viewed av1, (SELECT count(av.sesskey) as total, av.sesskey sesskey FROM also_viewed av 
      WHERE av.sesskey NOT IN (SELECT op.sesskey FROM orders_products op) GROUP BY av.sesskey HAVING total = 1) AS query
WHERE av1.sesskey = query.sesskey

Comment: @betus, you can if you quote it with backticks

Comment: Again here is the answer: DELETE av1 FROM also_viewed av1, (SELECT count(av.sesskey) as total, av.sesskey sesskey FROM also_viewed av WHERE av.sesskey NOT IN (SELECT op.sesskey FROM orders_products op) GROUP BY av.sesskey HAVING total = 1) AS query WHERE av1.sesskey = query.sesskey

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM also_viewed
WHERE   sesskey IN (
            SELECT  Distinct sesskey
            FROM    also_viewed
            WHERE   sesskey NOT IN (SELECT sesskey FROM order_products)
            GROUP BY sesskey
            HAVING  COUNT(1) = 1
        )
```

Comment: thx! but I would ask the same thing than The Elite Gentleman. Where is the "total" referenced

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I follow what you are trying to do. Can you backstep and explain what the goal of the entire query is?

Comment: Sure, also_viewed is a table that may contain repeated rows, and I want to delete the only one not repeated and not in the table orders_products

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my first question...but `total` is undefined.

Comment: Thx, but error ocurred: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'also_viewed' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Hmm... The query works in my test database on SQL Server. There must be something MySQL specific in the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

**Untested**

```
DELETE FROM also_viewed av 
WHERE av.sesskey NOT IN
    (SELECT op.sesskey FROM ORDERS_PRODUCTS op)
GROUP BY av.sesskey HAVING COUNT(av.sesskey) = 1;
```

Comment: Error! #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE av.sesskey NOT IN (SELECT op.sesskey from orders_products op) GROUP BY av.' at line 1

Comment: Try `DELETE FROM also_viewed WHERE sesskey NOT IN
    (SELECT op.sesskey FROM ORDERS_PRODUCTS op)
GROUP BY sesskey HAVING COUNT(sesskey) = 1;`

Comment: I'm sorry but is still having errors:#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY sesskey HAVING COUNT(sesskey) = 1' at line 1

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE av.sesskey NOT IN (SELECT op.sesskey FROM ORDERS_PRODUCTS op) GROUP BY av.' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

your sql is returning the number of matched rows not the rows itself
use the [delte syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/any-in-some-subqueries.html) in order to delete rows

```
delete from
  also_viewed
where
  sesskey not in(select op.sesskey from orders_products op)
```

PS: backup first; i am not entirely sure if i understood your query correctly